# Creating Power point slides with tables in Excel

Tags: vba, excel-2007, powerpoint-2007

I have a large workbook that has several connections and queries to an Oracle database to gather data.

I have roughly 6 sheets in this workbook that contain my final data.

I would like to move all of this data to a PowerPoint presentation.  I have seen many examples of how to move charts and graphs, but I have none of these in my workbook nor do I need them.

3 of my sheets display data generated by a pivot table on a separate sheet.  I have done this because I am trying to avoid showing the pivot filter arrows.

The other three sheets are a table created from the Oracle query.  Each sheet has a separate query to display data specific to a certain customer.

I would like to take the data I have in my spreadsheets and build tables in PowerPoint containing that data.  I have tried importing the objects to PowerPoint, but since the data can change from minute to minute having to update the links and then refresh the data is rather clumsy.  Also, I never know how many rows of data I will have.  This is also due to the fact that the data can change minute by minute.

In short I am trying to look at Sheet one.  Take all of the data there and build a table in PowerPoint to match.  When building the table in PowerPoint only place a max number of 6 rows per PowerPoint slide.  Continue to add slides until all of the data is moved.

Comment: Hope this link helps : http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/powerpoint-help/create-and-format-powerpoint-tables-HA001159309.aspx http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/insert-an-excel-worksheet-in-powerpoint-HA102749288.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to cobble together bits of the following that my friends Brian and Naresh have allowed my to post on the PowerPoint FAQ site I maintain, but between the two, it should get you there:

Controlling Office Applications from PowerPoint (by Naresh Nichani and Brian Reilly)
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00795_Controlling_Office_Applications_from_PowerPoint_-by_Naresh_Nichani_and_Brian_Reilly-.htm

Where it starts: the DisplayData project by Naresh Nichani and Brian Reilly
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00784_Where_it_starts-_the_DisplayData_project_by_Naresh_Nichani_and_Brian_Reilly.htm